# Format Strings in Console.WriteLine method

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

Im new to C# programming. Can someone please explain the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0}{1,10}", "Face", "Frequency" ); //Headings
Console.WriteLine( "{0,4}{1,10}",someval,anotherval);
```

I understand that this prints two columns of values with the headings given, and `{0}` refers to the first argument given. But what is the meaning of the format strings of the form `{x,y}` ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It adds padding to the left. Very useful for remembering the various string formatting patterns is the following cheat sheet:

> **[.NET String.Format Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20120803184243/http://www.dylanbeattie.net/cheatsheets/dot_net_string_format_cheat_sheet.pdf)**

Positive values add padding to the left, negative add padding to the right

```
Sample                                 Generates
String.Format("[{0, 10}]", "Foo");     [∙∙∙∙∙∙∙Foo]
String.Format("[{0, 5}]", "Foo");      [∙∙Foo]
String.Format("[{0, -5}]", "Foo");     [Foo∙∙]
String.Format("[{0, -10}]", "Foo");    [Foo∙∙∙∙∙∙∙]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 0xA3. If i understand correctly,does that mean {1,10} would print the second argument and 10 spaces immediately following it ?

Comment: @Joe: No, padding means that the string is filled up with blanks up to the length specified, see the example in my answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, this cheat sheet is completely wrong! The wrong index is used, and the positive/negative alignment is the opposite of what really happens. So, to produce `[∙∙∙∙∙∙∙Foo]`, you'd actually do `String.Format("[{0, 10}]", "Foo");`

Answer (score 8):

When you see `{x,y}`, `x` represents the argument's index and `y` the alignment, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). The complete syntax is the following:

```
{index[,alignment][:formatString]}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a padding value...if the argument isn't the length that is specified, it puts spaces in.

E.g. if you had {0,10} and the argument for {0} was "Blah", the actual value printed would be `"Blah<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>"`...Blah, with 6 extra spaces to make up a string of 10 length

ps - not sure how to put actual spaces in...need to look up SO faq no doubt