# Calling objects, methods and properties from one class and displaying them with information in another

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class called BaseRobot. Containing the following code:

```
//=== Defines the possible orientation of the robot.
//=== Note the order is important to allow cycling to be performed in a meaningful manner.
public enum Compass
{
    North, East, South, West
};

//=== The basic robot.
public class BaseRobot
{
    //--- The behaviour properties that were identified, together with associated state.
    //--- The robot identification number.
   private int mId;
   public int id
   {
       get { return mId; }
   }

   //--- the direction in which the robot is currently facing.
   private Compass mOrientation;
   public Compass Orientation
   {
       get { return mOrientation; }
       set { mOrientation = value; }
   }

   //--- The robot's current position.
   private Point mPosition;
   public Point Position
   {
       get { return mPosition; }
   }


   //--- the robot's home position, where it was originally created.
   public Point mHome;
   public Point Home
   {
       get { return mHome; }
   }

    //--- Turn the orientation left (anti-clockwise) or right (clockwise).
    //--- Implementation relies on the N, E, S, W ordering of the enumeration values to allow the arithmetic to work.

    public void TurnLeft()
    {
        --mOrientation;
        if (mOrientation < 0) mOrientation = Compass.West;
    } // end turnLeft method.    

    public void TurnRight()
    {
        mOrientation = (Compass)(((int)mOrientation + 1) % 4);
    } // end turnRight method.

    //--- Move one unit forward in the current orientation.
    public void Move()
    {
        switch (mOrientation)
        {
            case Compass.North: mPosition.Y++; break;
            case Compass.East: mPosition.X++; break;
            case Compass.South: mPosition.Y--; break;
            case Compass.West: mPosition.X--; break;
        }
    } // end Move method.

    //--- Constructor methods.
    public BaseRobot(int aId)
    {
        mId = aId;
        mHome.X = 0;
        mHome = new Point(0, 0);
        mPosition = mHome;
    }
    public BaseRobot(int aId, int aX, int aY)
    {
        mId = aId;
        mHome = new Point(aX, aY);
        mPosition = mHome;
    } // end BaseRobot constructor methods.
}
```

In the program class, i am looking to call the objects, methods and properties from this code to display information regrading the robot's status, such as robot home, orientation and position. I am looking for the console to display something like this:

Robot has home at <0,0>
It is facing North and is currently at <0,0>

Any ideas of how i can achieve this?

Comment: Does your program have an instance of `BaseRobot`?

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you to read about [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). That will make your code look like:

```
public Point Home { get; private set; }
public Point Position { get; private set; }
public Compass Orientation { get; private set; }
```

Now back to formatting your robot to string. You can override `ToString()` method of robot class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return String.Format("Robot has home at {0} It is facing {1} and is currently at {2}",
                        mHome, mOrientation, mPosition);
}
```

Or simply pass robot instance to following method:

```
public void WriteToConsole(BaseRobot robot)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Robot has home at {0} It is facing {1} and is currently at {2}",
                     robot.Home, robot.Orientation, robot.Position);
}
```

NOTE: By default System.Drawing.Point class will be converted to string `{X=42,Y=8}`. If you need it formatted as `<42,8>` then you should manually provide values for X and Y like this:

```
String.Format("Robot has home at <{0},{1}> It is facing {2} and is currently at <{3},{4}>", 
              Home.X, Home.Y, Orientation, Position.X, Position.Y);
```

Or if Point is your own class, then simply override it's `ToString()` method:

```
return String.Format("<{0},{1}>", X, Y);
```

Comment: Your string needs to be encapsulated in "". ;)

Comment: We all forget something sometimes, it's not a big deal. :p

Comment: How could i change the code so that the robot is facing south?

Comment: @user2657462 this code outputs current orientation. If it's not oriented to south, then turn it until robot will face south

Comment: @lazyberezosky How do i turn the the robot in the main program?

Comment: @user2657462 `BaseRobot robot = new BaseRobot(1, 0, 0); Console.WriteLine(robot); robot.TurnRight(); Console.WriteLine(robot);`

Answer (score 0):

Try Console.WriteLine, calling your class methods to get the argument values, see here for more

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aakt1eab.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223815/format-strings-in-console-writeline-method) can be used to achieve this easily.

You can use [Console.Writeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx), like so:

```
// Assumes a Robot r exists already
Console.Writeline("Robot has home at <{0},{1}> and is facing {2} and is currently at <{3},{4}>", r.Home.X, r.Home.Y, r.Orientation, r.Position.X, r.Position.Y);
```

[Overriding ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) is another way of doing this:

```
public override string ToString(){
    return string.Format("Robot has home at <{0},{1}> and is facing {2} and is currently at <{3},{4}>", Home.X, Home.Y, Orientation, Position.X, Position.Y);
}
```

Overriding ToString() doesn't seem correct here, however, because you're displaying status information about a Robot that isn't really the "string representation of a robot", which is what ToString() should be supplying. I'd either use the Console.Writeline method above, or have a string Status property on Robot to get this type of information.