# Is there a way to go back and add something to a line that's already been printed?

Tags: c#

I have a function that initiates and prints out a matrix

```
int[,] LotteryArray = new int[Rows,Columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < LotteryArray.GetLength(0); i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < LotteryArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                LotteryArray[i, j] = RandomNum(1, 46);   
                Console.Write("{0,3},", LotteryArray[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return LotteryArray;
```

i have another function, that calls `LotteryArray` and then checks each row of it to see if the "winning" numbers are there and then prints out how many "winning" numbers are in each row.

i did this

```
for (int j = 0; j < LotteryArray.GetLength(0); j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < LotteryArray.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Winner.Length; i++)  
                {
                    if (Winner[i] == LotteryArray[j, k])
                    {
                        Prediction++;
                    }
                }
            }
            RowNum++;
            Console.WriteLine("You got {0} predictions correct in row {1}", Prediction, RowNum);
            Prediction = 0;
        }
```

but it prints it out one line after the matrix, but i want to print out after each line in the already printed matrix. is there a way for me to do that?

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
you got yada yada yada in line 1
you got yada yada yada in line 2 
you got yada yada yada in line 3
```

is how it looks like

and i want to look like this

```
1,2,3,4,5      you got x predictions correct here
1,2,3,4,5      yada yada yada
1,2,3,4,5      yada yada yada
```

sorry if this is a stupid question, i'm a beginner

Edit: thank you for the answers everyone i'll play around with `Console.SetCursorPosition` and make it pretty

Comment: `Console.SetCursorPosition`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @B0Andrew would the single digit numbers mess that up? also is there a way to do that without counting the spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1,2,3,4,5");
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 0);
    Console.Write("you got x predictions correct here");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: yes but i have a followup question: will the single digit numbers mess it up (6 double digit number will be longer than 5 double digit numbers and one single digit number). and is there a way to do this without counting the spaces?

Comment: @Muffinator you will probably want to format your matrix based on the maximum value (or in your case test if you have any value >= 10). Then each line of the matrix will have the same length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223815/format-strings-in-console-writeline-method

Comment: @Muffinator Yes, it may do. If the first parameter is too small, the printed number will be replaced. So you'd better set a fixed field width for all your numbers, or just simply save every printed line to an array.