# Formatting Output in C# With Curly Brackets

Tags: c#

What do the values within the curly brackets do in this example?

```
{
 double price = 1234.56
 Console.WriteLine("TV{0:F0} is {1:C}" , 2, price);
 Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Strings in Console.WriteLine method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223815/format-strings-in-console-writeline-method)

Answer (score 3):

Basically the first number ist the index of the argument (`0` means `2`, `1` means  `price` in your example).

The value after the colon is one of the Standard Numeric Format Strings, see [MSDN-Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for available options.

- `{0:F0}` prints `2` because parameter 0 is `2`  and format is Fixed Point with zero decimal places (`F0`)
- `{1:C}` prints `$1234,56`becaus parameter 1 (`price`) is `1234.56` and format is Currency (`C`)

This example uses only Format Strings for numerics, there are also Standard Format Strings for `DateTime` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

> What do the values within the curly brackets do in this example?

They are format specifications for the values provided. Essentially, it instructs the `Console.WriteLine` function how to format the values as strings for output to the console. [Here is a .NET fiddle that exemplifies this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7uyO0O).

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) has an extensive example that shows how these work.

1. `{0:F0}` takes the given `2` int value, and simply prints it as `2`, "2"
2. `{1:C}` takes the given `1234.56` double value and treats it as currency, "$1,234.45".

The `0` and `1` are significant as they are the zero-based array indicator of the location in which the parameters map to the string formatting. For example, the below demonstrates outputs from altering the arguments to better visualize the impact.

```
Console.WriteLine("TV{0:F0} is {1:C}", 2, price);  // Prints TV2 is $1,234.56
Console.WriteLine("TV{0:F0} is {1:C}", price, 2);  // Prints TV1234 is $2.00
```